# Batch windows - read file and modify line

Tags: batch-file

I want to automate  some actions with a batch script, one thing I have to do, is to replace a date on a file, with the current date. I tried to do something, dut it's like the line of my file is empty...

```
SET planningFile=<My file with full path>

set mydate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%

FOR /F %%i IN ('TYPE "%planningFile%"') DO (
    SET str=%%i
    SET str=%str:~8,%
    ECHO %mydate%%srt% > "%planningFile%~"
)
DEL "%planningFile%"
RENAME "%planningFile%~" "%planningFile%"
```

a line of that file looks like `20140513;54;aaaa:54` (CSV file).
Anyone could help me ?

Comment: + the `RENAME` command seems doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Hence

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%i IN ('TYPE "%planningFile%"') DO (
    SET "str=%%i"
    SET "str=!str:~8!"
    ECHO %mydate%!sTR! > "%planningFile%~"
)
```

Note : - your line has `ECHO ...%srt% ....

**The `>` should be `>>` if you wish to append rather than create the file anew**.

See any number of SO articles on `delayedexpansion` for hundreds of examples.